# Brother HL-1210W won't print

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, network-printer, brother-printer

We have a Brother HL-1210W laser printer on the network, which is connected through wireless internet. The discovery and installation of the device is not a problem and Windows installs it without any error. But when we try to print any document (even the test pages of windows) it would fail. The task is in the queue, but the printer won't print anything. When we cancel the task or refresh the printer spooler, sometimes part of the document is printed and then the printer stopped.

We tried a lot:

- Removing printers and reinstalling them
- Reinstalling drivers and official driver software
- Removing every Register Item and Program that was linked to the printer
- Changing from WSD to TCP/IP port
- Printing directly to printer instead of using spooler
- Completely resetting printer
- The Microsoft Printer Troubleshooter, online version with more tests which couldn't identify any problem
- Probably a lot more that I'm forgetting right now...

Also, when I tried to ping the printer only 50% of the packets were correctly received. I guess this is not normal? I thought about a duplicate IP but as far as I could see there were no duplicates and we even tried giving it a fixed IP that wasn't on the network before.

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I assume you followed directions at https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl1210w_eu_as&faqid=faq00002794_030 *verbatim*. Have you tried connecting directly by USB, e.g. from a laptop, to see if that works? Perhaps the printer is defective.

Comment: It's actually for a friend. They don't have a USB-B cable, but I told them to buy one as a back-up possibility. We did what is described on that page (with a downloaded version of the installer) and as I said, the connection itself seems okay. Printer is probably not defective, they have two brother laser printers and they are both behaving the same. It's HL-1210W and DCP-9015CDW.